# What's the connection between differential equations and data to approximate a function

Tags: partial-differential-equations, stochastic-processes

Does anyone know how a differential equation can be solved using data? As far as I know differential equations are already representing the relationship between two or more variables and one can use analytical or numerical methods to find the function of interest. But data driven statistical approaches for function approximation take different approach compared to differential equations. Recently I have seen some works like [this](https://rss.onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/pdfdirect/10.1111/j.1467-9868.2011.00777.x) that use differential equations (SPDE to be specific) to solve a function approximation problem using data and I couldn't understand where exactly data is being used with the differential equation to find the solution. If anyone can explain in simple terms how differential equations could work with data to approximate an unknown function I would appreciate it.

Comment: Differential equations and more likely integral equations can be involved in regression methods to fit  functions to data. Elementary examples are shown in this paper : https://fr.scribd.com/doc/14674814/Regressions-et-equations-integrales